# Почему в SplObjectStorage в массиве ключем является объект? Зачем это нужно?

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Начал разбираться с SplObjectStorage. 
Можете, пожалуйста, "на пальцах" объяснить, почему в SplObjectStorage в качестве ключа массива хранятся объекты? А value элементов массива - это их значения. Какой смысл в том, чтобы ключами элементов массива были объекты? Или что это дает

```
$s = new SplObjectStorage();

$o1 = new StdClass;
$o2 = new StdClass;
$o3 = new StdClass;

$s[$o1] = "данные для объекта 1";
$s[$o2] = array(1,2,3);
$s->attach($o3);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($s);
echo '</pre>';
```

ниже: результат вызова echo print_r($s)

```
SplObjectStorage Object
(
    [storage:SplObjectStorage:private] => Array
        (
            [0000000001db526e00000000729ed9e8] => Array
                (
                    [obj] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                    [inf] => данные для объекта 1
                )

            [0000000001db526f00000000729ed9e8] => Array
                (
                    [obj] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                    [inf] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 2
                            [2] => 3
                        )

                )

            [0000000001db526800000000729ed9e8] => Array
                (
                    [obj] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                    [inf] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Если почитать еще раз внимательно документацию...

Comment: Читал. Документация говорит так: "Класс SplObjectStorage предоставляет отображение объектов в данные или набор объектов, игнорируя данные. Эта двойная цель может быть полезна во многих случаях, включая необходимость уникальной идентификации объектов." Получается, что данные нужны только для того, чтобы сгенирировать хеш, который потом будет id-шником для каждого элемента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не записывать, а потом игнорировать, а "двойная цель".

Вообще говоря я с вами согласен. Перевод документации на русский это большая проблема. Причем явно что проблема не в русском, а обычно, как водится, в переводчике. Русский чувак постоянно хочет всё усложнить.

> The SplObjectStorage class provides a map from objects to data or, by
>   ignoring data, an object set.

Здесь говорится о том что SplObjectStorage может служить двояко.
Представьте себе что SplObjectStorage это некая структура данных в которой позволительна разная реализация.

Вариант 1 - в SplObjectStorage конкретный объект может быть ключем в массиве к данным. 
Вариант 2 - SplObjectStorage является набором объектов. (для которых существуют разные ООП style функции).

Вы вольны пользоваться любым из вариантов.

Нужно ли этим пользоваться - ваше решение.

Давайте еще раз - исползование данного класса двояко. У вас вопрос про использования объекта как ключа , есть же использование как набора объектов. Посмотрите реализуемые интерфейсы и в общем то методы и поймете зачем это нужно.