# SplObjectStorage извлечь объект

Tags: php

Как извлечь первый объект из SplObjectStorage?

Ничего лучше не придумал, можно это сделать как то иначе?

```php
$Obj = iterator_to_array($SPL)[0];
```

Пробовал так (возвращает `null`):

```php
$SPL->rewind();
$Obj = $SPL->current(); // :null
```

Используется он для хранения подкатегорий в каталоге, и на сколько понял (код писал не я), для того что бы не было дубликатов.

Читал во [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1079381/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-splobjectstorage-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE) про SplObjectStorage, и от части разделяю непонимание, чем он лучше массива или может чем то удобнее, объясните пожалуйста.

**UPD:**

`$SPL->next()` так же  возвращает `null`,

`var_dump($SPL);` :

```
object(SplObjectStorage)#807 (1) {
  ["storage":"SplObjectStorage":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["0000000009d35fca00000000516ba508"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["obj"]=>
        ...
      ["inf"]=>
      int(6)
    }
    ...
```

**UPD_2:**

```php
class Category{
  ...
  public function __construct(int $id = null)
  {
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->subCategories = new \SplObjectStorage();
  }
  ...
  public function addSubCategory(Category &$category)
  {
    if ($this->subCategories->contains($category)) {
      return;
    }
    $this->subCategories->attach($category, $category->id);
  }
  ...
  public function child(){
    return $this->subCategories;
  }
};

$Category = new Category();
...
$SPL = $Category->child();
$SPL->rewind();
$SPL->valid(); // :false
```

Comment: Насколько я понял, current возвращает объект только если $SPL->valid() возвращает true

Comment: @pgood Да точно, $SPL->valid() в моём случае возвращает false. "Возвращает true, если текущий объект допустим и false в противном случае." В каком случае объект может быть не допустим?

Comment: `false` возвращается если следующего объекта в итераторе __нет__. Это общее правило всех итераторов - возвращать `false` если больше объектов нет.

Comment: @u_mulder в этом случае, по идеи, тогда бы это не должно было бы сработать ‘iterator_to_array’

Comment: Что именно не должно было сработать?

Comment: @u_mulder `$SPL->rewind();` тут скидываю итератор в начало, `$SPL->valid()` возвращает `false`, но `iterator_to_array($SPL)` возвращает массив значит с итераторами все ок или я не верно рассуждаю

Comment: `iterator_to_array` берет все элементы итератора и помещает их в массив. Эта операция никак не связана со скидыванием итератора в начало.

Comment: @u_mulder да я понимаю, `iterator_to_array` возвращает мне все объекты внутри. Однако почему после того, как скинул итератор на начало, $SPL->valid() возвращает false _(не понимаю вот этот момент)_. То на сколько понимаю могло бы произойти если бы у итератора не было элементов,  а результат `iterator_to_array` говорит об обратном

Comment: Я не вижу всего кода, потому не могу ничего пояснить.

Comment: @u_mulder Обновил вопрос. В проекте не так же все, вставил момент создания вставки и запроса к итератору, ибо не знаю как это все целиком показать(

Comment: Ну я не вижу где добавляется хотя бы одна субкатегория. Если добавить - то все нормально https://3v4l.org/Cf4Gi

Comment: @u_mulder так у меня тоже работает, сейчас ещё внимательней постараюсь по коду пройтись. Дамп $SPL показывает там SplObjectStorage, запутался, буду разбираться